# How to create a synonym for a column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017, synonyms

The following is not working. I want to create a synonym on a column in SQL Server 2017. How would I go about doing this?

```
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.[ProductTest] for [dbo].[Product].[ProductId]
GO

select ProductTest from dbo.Product
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to retain the table name but refer to an existing column by a new name a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017) will do this for you. The computed value of the column will be just the value of the existing column.

```
alter table [dbo].[Product]
add [ProductTest] as ([ProductId]);
```

Now you can write

```
select
    [ProductId],
    [ProductTest] 
from [dbo].[Product];
```

The two columns will have the same value, always.

If you reference only the computed column my guess is there won't even be a run-time overhead.

Answer (score 8):

You can't create a synonym for a column; synonyms are simple redirects to first class entities like tables and stored procedures. [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql) lists the object types that are candidates (and column is not in the list):

Synonyms can be created for the following types of objects:

```
CLR Stored Procedure             CLR Table-valued Function
CLR Scalar Function              CLR Aggregate Functions
Replication-filter-procedure     Extended Stored Procedure
Scalar Function                  Table-valued Function
Inline-table-valued Function     Stored Procedure
View                             Table1
```

To simulate a synonym, if you can't change the table, you can create a view, and force users to access the view instead of the table:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vProduct
AS
  SELECT ProductTest = ProductID FROM dbo.Product;
```

Or control access through a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Product_Get
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SELECT ProductTest = ProductID FROM dbo.Product;
END
GO
```

If you already have a stored procedure that selects the original column name and you want to conditionally return the alias instead of the original, *sometimes*, you can use `WITH RESULT SETS`. The downside is you must define the data type:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Product_Get_v2
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SELECT ProductID FROM dbo.Product;
END
GO

EXEC dbo.Product_Get_v2;
-- returns column ProductID

EXEC dbo.Product_Get_v2 WITH RESULT SETS ((ProductTest int));
-- returns column ProductTest
```

If you can change the table and it needs to be more transparent, you can create a computed column, [as Michael Green suggests](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/227137/1186). Just note that now both columns will come back in `SELECT *` and you'll have to update any stored procedures, views, or application code that currently references the old name.